# Change MSSQL Schema Ownership via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, schema, smo

I'm trying to change the "schemas owned by this user" on a database using the following powershell script:

```
$dbname = "mydb"
$sql_server = "mysqlserver"
$username = "myuser"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server")($sql_server)
$db = $server.Databases["$dbname"]
$login = $server.Logins[$username]
$roleName = "db_owner"

if(-not $db.Users.Contains($login.Name)){
    $user = New-Object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User') $db, $login.Name
    $user.Login = $login.Name
    $user.create();
}

$user = $db.Users[$login.Name]       
$role = $db.Roles[$roleName]
$role.AddMember($user.Name);

$schema = $db.Schemas["dbo"]
$schema.Owner = "myuser"
$schema.Alter()
```

When I get to the step $schema.Alter() I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Alter" with "0" argument(s): "Alter failed for Schema 'dbo'. "
At line:1 char:1
+ $schema.Alter()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

I get the impression the Alter Method is looking for more parameters but I'm not sure what parameters it wants. Anyone have any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: I'm using this as a rough guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/creating-altering-and-removing-schemas Not sure what I'm doing wrong? It seems like from the example I'm doing this right.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the top level exception is not helpful. My typical method for dealing with this is something like `$e = $error[0];` and then calling `$e.Exception`, `$e.Exception.InnerException`, `$e.Exception.InnerException.InnerException`, … until I get to the *actual* error. This doesn't solve your problem, but at least can give you a better idea of what the problem *is*.

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately not a lot more to go on. Besides the error above the only additional line was: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. Which is still pretty vague.

Comment: If I just add $schema I see the owner has changed and I think .Alter() should commit the change but apparently something's not right.

Comment: Correct on the "vague error". You've gotta go all the way down (Inception style) until you get to the root of the problem. That is, I think you got the "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch." from `$e.Exception.InnerException`. What does `$e.Exception.InnerException.InnerException` give you? Keep adding calls to `InnerException` until you get something that looks like the reason or until it returns `$null`.

Comment: Adding .InnerException doesn't help. The most detailed error I can get is this: Exception calling "Alter" with "0" argument(s): "Alter failed for Schema 'dbo'. "
Alter failed for Schema 'dbo'.
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
Cannot alter the schema 'dbo'.